# VB6 on Windows XP - LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file "Path/To/File/Its/Making"

Tags: linker, vb6, fatal-error

I'm to continue maintenance on several programs called "Legacy Projects". I have a separate Windows XP system for that.

Most of these are VB6 programs. I have one to which I was forced to make changes. Only now it refuses to make the new executable, giving the above error message :

`LINK : fatal error LNK1104: cannot open file "C:\Documents And Settings\Me\My Documents\VB6 Projects\Some Directory Path Name\MyProjectDirectory\MyProjectExecutable.exe`

I've opened an older version of the project and it compiled and created the executable fine.

Out of frustration, I created a brand new project, moved the source files ( forms, modules and class modules ) over to it, and tried again. It failed. Again. Still.

Why.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll take a guess on insufficient information.

> PRB: LINK Fatal Error LNK1104 Cannot Open File
>
> Q166470
>
> SYMPTOMS
>
> When compiling an ActiveX component with binary compatibility set to the same file the compile is attempting to overwrite, the following error occurs:
>
> ```
> LINK fatal error LNK1104 cannot open file.
> ```
>
> RESOLUTION
>
> To work around this problem, copy the ActiveX executable or DLL to a separate directory. Set binary compatibility to the copied file, and
> compile to the original directory. This procedure is described in
> Microsoft Visual Basic Books Online.

More generally you could have looked up the VC++ linker reference, which all MS languages use.

> Linker Tools Error LNK1104 cannot open file "filename"
>
> The tool could not open the given file.
>
> Tips
>
> One of the following may be a cause:
>
> There was not enough disk space.
>
> The file does not exist.
>
> The filename or its path was incorrectly specified.
>
> The specified drive is invalid.
>
> The file does not have the appropriate permissions.
>
> The path for filename expands to more than 260 characters.
>
> If the given file is named LNKn, which is a filename generated by the
> linker for a temporary file, then the directory specified in the TMP
> environment variable may not exist, or more than one directory is
> specified for the TMP environment variable. (Only one directory path
> should be specified for the TMP environment variable.)
>
> **If the error occurs on the executable filename, an earlier version of
> the executable may still be running. You will need to terminate the
> executable before linking it. In Windows NT or Windows 95 you can use
> the utility PVIEW to look for and kill instances of the application.
> PVIEW.EXE is shipped with Visual C++.**
>
> If the error message occurs for a library name, and you recently
> ported the .MAK file from a previous Microsoft Visual C++ development
> system, the library may no longer be valid. Ensure that the library
> still exists in this circumstance.